# Setting a max int value (not character count) to a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, int, uitextfield, max

In Swift, is it possible to set a max INT value to a UITextField?

My use-case is I have 5 text fields that need to have a maximum int value. These values range from 500 all the way to 10,000. Each of the 5 different text fields will have a different max. I can't use a picker or dropdown because the increments will be 1. And a UISlider will be way too tough to "scrub in" on the number.

If the max int value is 5,000, user can not type in (on the keyboard type of number pad) a value any higher than 5000.

Character count won't work, because if the max value is 500, if I set to 3 characters, user can type in 999.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if the current value in the text field is less than the maximum integer value you've specified:

*(You might want to change the keyboard type to `.NumberPad` at this point to let user type only numeric values.)*

```
textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
```

--

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  let newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
  if newText.isEmpty {
    return true
  }
  else if let intValue = Int(newText) where intValue <= self.maxValue {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

I created an [example project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4450hpnrhw1u1dh/AADl5P_Koj5ura1Wq9mOaNhJa?dl=0) for you. You can download and play around with it.

Comment: thank you!! this seems to do what i need. Question though, what is the benefit of using a property observer on maxValue?

Comment: Let's say you decreased max value from 5000 to 2000 and the current value in the text input is 3000. So it'd better for you to clear everything out and start over.

Comment: i didn't even think of that. perfect. THANK YOU!

Comment: Having just a tiny bit of difficulty implementing this into my project. I created an extension on the VC and added the shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate method. however - my text field is "enterIntMax" (not textField, like in your example). I can't figure out what to change in the method for it to work with enterIntMax

Comment: [`shouldChangeCharactersInRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) is delegate method so you should set the delegate of `enterIntMax` to VC first. `textField` is automatically passed into the method, so you can check `textField == enterIntMax` inside it.

Comment: Got it to work. I just added enterIntMax.delegate = self in viewdidload. The IBOutlet you set was textField, which is also defined in the delegate method, that's where my confusion was.

Comment: Never rely on the keyboard type. A user can still copy and paste other text or they can use an external keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update for Swift 4 and later that ensure the value entered is an integer in the range 0 to 5000.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String
    if let num = Int(newText), num >= 0 && num <= 5000 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```